# Response from specific URL is not valid text, when using CURL (works fine in browser)

Tags: http, curl

This url responds with JSON text if I visit it in a browser, however trying to `get` it with CURL I get what appears to be a binary data that doesn't constitute a valid string. I'm not sure what's going on. It's simple to reproduce, just try this url in your browser and then with CURL:
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/SanFrancisco_Bldgs/SceneServer/layers/0?f=json

In the browser you'll get JSON text but in CURL, you'll get

```
?
?Vmo?H?+??z??1??P?tMҐ... etc
```

I have been dealing with many similar urls and have never run into this before. Really apreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. Both the proposed solutions below work well. Saved the day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked the headers of the response. The server is sending the response in GZIP compression mode. Most of the modern browsers can de-compress automatically but not cURL.
[image]

We have to unzip the response to get actual data. You can use cURL along with  **gunzip**.

Finally, your curl command looks like this :

```
$curl https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/SanFrancisco_Bldgs/SceneServer/layers/0?f=json  | gunzip -
```

Answer (score 1):

I have compared the difference for you, the browser request server with compression, so you can try `curl --compressed`